# Node demand Allocation in Water Distribution Network

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am completely new to this QGIS. I have been given a task to automate node demand (amount of water needed). I have a "XYZ" district data set which include:

- district shp files,
- village road shp files,
- Highway Road shp files,
- elevationpoints shp files.
- I have a populations file of that district too.

Now

> node demand=(population region of area) * (Average liter of water consumed by a person in a day ).

I need to write a python code so that it can automated and save man power and time.

How should I start step by step in QGIS to achieve this goal?